# Installing Cygwin in Windows Docker container

Tags: docker, cygwin

An attempt to install Cygwin in an Docker container on Windows fails with the error:

```
re-exec error: exit status 1: output: time="2020-12-11T15:00:26+01:00" level=error msg="hcsshim::ImportLayer - failed failed in Win32: The system cannot find the path specified. (0x3)" error="hcsshim::ImportLayer - failed failed in Win32: The system cannot find the path specified. (0x3)" importFolderPath="D:\\docker\\tmp\\hcs678884955" path="\\\\?\\D:\\docker\\windowsfilter\\9b956fcbc6cf19ba2f18fe39e12639da939e14916f019a32541df16e7dbf5b1e"
hcsshim::ImportLayer - failed failed in Win32: The system cannot find the path specified. (0x3)
```

At https://github.com/microsoft/hcsshim/issues/835, they write that hardlinks are the reason for the problem. Zipping/unzipping the CygWin folder should help fix it but, using Cygwin installer, you have no control over the unattended installation.

Is there any other method for how Cygwin can be installed in a Docker container?

Is it possible to suppress the creation of hardlinks by Cygwin installer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by the fact that cygwin is using hard links that seems cause docker to fail, try to install cygwin locally, then zip & unzip into the separate folder, they simply add cygwin using [`ADD`](https://docs.docker.com/reference/dockerfile/#add).

Comment: Can you elaborate on the last step "Simply add using ADD"? What is ADD? Active directory domain?